# In Azure IoT Central, when does the device telemetry data get deleted when the device is deleted?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am programmatically setting up some tests with IoT Central.  I want to be able to delete the devices and then recreate them with the same Device ID and create new telemetry data for the device.

It seems that when i delete the device in the IoT Central UI, and then provision a device with the same Device ID, the telemetry data is still associated with the new device.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iot *Device ID* is an unique in the iot streaming pipeline and there is no workaround to delete its history or filtering them in the past. You should wait for retention policy or using some versioning in the device ID.